# Read only certain rows from xls with R

Tags: r

I know it is possible to read only certain columns with the package XLConnect. But is it also possible to only read certain rows?

```
demoExcelFile <- system.file("demoFiles/mtcars.xlsx", package = "XLConnect")  
wb <- loadWorkbook(demoExcelFile)
# Read the columns 1, 3 and 5 from the sheet 'mtcars' (with default header = TRUE)
data <- readWorksheet(wb, sheet = "mtcars", keep=c(1,3,5))
```

1. Edit: For consecutive rows, there is a possibility. Is there a possiblity for non-consecutive rows? So far, my method is to delete the "other" rows which aren't needed (but that is a lot of typing).

Comment: According to `?readWorksheet`, yes, if it's a block of consecutive rows, through options `startRow` and `endRow`. If not, probably no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

read all rows using readWorksheet and then select certain rows from data.frame you've got

for example:

```
data <- readWorksheet(wb, sheet = "mtcars") 
new.data <- data[c(10, 20, 30), ]
```